# Pass two parameters from main report to subreport OF SAME DATASET in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, parameter-passing, report

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport1.rpt"));
string firstparameter= "abc";
rd.SetParameterValue("name", firstparameter);
rd.SetParameterValue("name", firstparameter,        
rd.Subreports[0].Name.ToString());    
string secondparameter="xyz" ;
rd.SetParameterValue("last", secondparameter);
rd.SetParameterValue("last", secondparameter, 
rd.Subreports[1].Name.ToString());         
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
```

I just want to pass second parameter to both report but it 
   gives me this error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size
>   of the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: i just want to pass second parameter to both report but it 
    gives me this error...
    Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size 
    of the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: Why are you calling `rd.SetParameterValue("name", firstparameter);` *twice*, (and forgetting a closing `)` on the second call)? You also do this for `rd.SetParameterValue("last", secondparameter);`